# Add a batch file extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I Have a want too add in the extension `.btm` too act just like a batch file, is there **any** way I could do that and possibly permanently add it into my registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's my investigation over the topic](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6511)

As the simply using assoc will not work .I use a temp file that renames the file with bat extension .There's still room form improvements (e.g. the temp file could be deleted) , but is the only way that I've found to make a file with a different extension to act like /bat/cmd. This does not edit the %PATHEXT% so if you want to call these wiles without extension you'll need to edit by yourself.

First create a `bat` file that looks like this:

```
@echo off 
copy "%~nx1"  "%temp%\%~nx1.bat" /Y >nul 
"%temp%\%~nx1.bat"  %2
```

and save  it as `"%ProgramFiles%\caller\caller.bat"`

Then create a `.bat` file like this and run it as administrator:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;REM
;REM -------- THIS IS INSTALLMENT PART --------
;REM
;@ECHO OFF
;CLS
;BREAK
;BREAK -- CREATING THE EXTENSION CALLER 
;BREAK
;
;echo @echo off > %temp%\caller.temp
;echo copy "%%~nx1"  "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat" /Y ^>nul >>%temp%\caller.temp
;echo "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat"  %%2>>%temp%\caller.temp
;
;md "%ProgramFiles%\caller" >nul 2>&1
;copy "%temp%\caller.temp"  "%ProgramFiles%\caller\caller.bat" /Y >nul 2>&1
;
;BREAK
;BREAK -- CALLING REGEDIT
;BREAK
;
;REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
;GOTO :EOF
;
;REM
;REM -------- HERE STARTS THE REGISTRY PART --------
;REM




;this links the information for the extension to
;HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\btmfile
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.btm]
@="cmffile"

;this is used by windows search
;it's value indicates that it contains only text
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.btm\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

;This is the other part of the registry which is edited
;here is contained the actual information
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\btmfile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\btmfile\DefaultIcon]
@="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\imageres.dll,-68"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\btmfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\btmfile\shell\Run]

;Unfortunately does not work with %ProgramFiles%
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\btmfile\shell\Run\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\caller\\caller.bat\" \"%1\" %*"
```

Comment: That's going to not work correctly if the batch file depends on its directory to be its current working directory.